# Android Show Different Image on Different Resolution

Tags: android, pixel

I am attempting to create a very graphically intensive android application. Almost all of the UI is based on bitmaps and I would like to support as many different devices as possible and to have the app look great in all of them.

Is it possible to embed different resolutions for each image and have a different image displayed on each device. I am aware of stuff like hdpi folders etc. as well has units like dip etc., but that still leaves too many variables as to how the image is displayed. I would like to not have the images scaled at all to avoid losing image quality.

For instance on my high resolution device I would like an image to be exactly 100px and then on a medium resolution device I would like a lower resolution image to display and be exactly 80px. If I use display independent units, I cannot ensure that the images will be of a particular size.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of dpi (hdpi etc) and orientation (land/port) to make the resources as customized as possible on different screens.

Additionally in your ImageView's specify android:scaleType="fitCenter" or android:scaleType="centerCrop" to accommodate non-standard resolutions.

Comment: I am going to attempt to just use different layouts for the different screen sizes. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: did you find any alternative way?